# How to use KeyListener without a button or text area?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am writing a game program using Java Swing and want to get user response for movement directly from keyboard, instead of making them press buttons. But all the tutorials I found need to bind the action with a button and then associate the action with buttons.

Is there a way to let the program respond by just pressing the keys?

Comment: You'll want to use [the key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).  When someone mentions `KeyListener`, please, do yourself a favour an ignore them, when other focusable components on the UI, `KeyListener` will just screw you up

Comment: For example, see [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for a working example of Key Bindings

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWTEventListeners. They are catching any Event, regardless of which Component will eventually receive it (no need to have any Components listening, I tested it with one `JLabel` in a `JFrame`). If it is absolutely necessary to use a `KeyListener` you need to do manual conversion.

Example of such a conversion for a `MouseListener` (should be similar with a `KeyListener`):

```
if(event.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
    listener.mousePressed(mouseEvent);
}
```

*Note: I have made Swing Games myself too and while it does work you will run into performance issues if you try to render lots of stuff and making images render more efficiently can become very complicated.

So if you for example have a Tiled Map that creates dozens of square images just for the terrain and then add multiple npcs and lots of bullets on top your game will likely be unplayable.*


Here's a small Example that prints Key Codes on Key / Mouse press and Mouse coordinates when it's moved. Also quits the application if `ESCAPE` is pressed:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
        if(event instanceof KeyEvent){
            KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent) event;
            if(keyEvent.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED){
                System.out.println("Key pressed: " + keyEvent.getKeyCode());
                if(keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }else if(event instanceof MouseEvent){
            MouseEvent mouseEvent = (MouseEvent) event;
            if(mouseEvent.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED){
                System.out.println("Mouse pressed: " + mouseEvent.getButton());
            }else if(mouseEvent.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED){
                System.out.println("Mouse moved to " + mouseEvent.getXOnScreen() + "/" + mouseEvent.getYOnScreen());
            }
        }
    }
}, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK + AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK + AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK);
```